# Check if an element of a list is in every list of a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

as the title already states I want to check if an element (doesn't matter which one) of a list matches at least one element of every list in a nested list in Python 3.7.

Here is an example:

```
possible_moves = [(3,4), (3,5), (3,6)]

sum_of_lists = [
    [(5,5), (5,6), (5,7)],
    [(2,3), (2,2), (2,1), (2,0)],
    [(6,4), (5,4), (4,4), (3,4), (2,4)]
]
```

I'm sure it can be done with for loops and `break`/`continue`, but this problem gives me a hard time. I was able to get the following code myself:

```
# going through my first list
for position in possible_moves:
    
    # going through all sub lists in the nested list
    for sub_list in sum_of_lists:
        
        # going through every element of the sub_list
        for move in sub_list:
            
            # now checking if my position element matches the move element of the sub_list
            if position == move:
                
                # at this point i want to go to the next sub_list
                # code
            
            # if the position element does not match the move element i want to go to the next move
            # if the position element does not match with any of the move elements i want to return
            # an empty list and stop all loops
            elif position != move:
                # code
            
            # if any of my position elements matches at least one move element of all sub_lists i 
            # want to return a new list (e.g. matching_element = []) that contains the specific 
            # element and stop all loops
```

After that I will use a function that checks if the returned list is empty or not. If its empty it will return False and if its not empty it will return True.

Edit:

Okay, i will try to explain why I want to do this.

I am creating a chess game as my first programming (and python) project with python 3.7 and pygame. This problem occured while trying to create a working is_checkmate function that checks if a king is checkmate.

So, actually the thing I had in my mind was, that there are several conditions that have to be met:

First, the king should not be able to make a move where he can hide behind any friendly piece and not be in check anymore.

Second, it should not be possible that the attacker that checks the king can get destroyed by an enemy piece.

Third (which is where my question relates to), if several enemy pieces check the king and I have their paths as coordinates towards the king (represented by the sub_lists in `sum_of_lists`), I wanted to check if a king friendly piece could block all three ways with one of his possible moves (represented by `possible_moves`).

But to be honest, I just realised that this condition is useless because i think it is not possible that one king friendly piece can block the path of several enemy pieces that check the king at the same time.

I hope you understand what I mean because I have no clue of how to explain it better.

Comment: I think you are trying to do something the wrong way. The structure is really bad for what you are trying to achieve. You should consider some kind of ordering, maybe a tree or something else. Please explain in more details about what you are after.

Comment: So you want to check if the tuples in `possible_moves` are in ***all*** the sub_lists of `sum_of_lists`? It is not really clear. Provide the expected output from the above example

Comment: `for position in possible_moves: print(all(position in sub_list for sub_list in sum_of_lists))`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo I want to know if there is a tuple in `possible_moves` that also occurs in every sub_list of `sum_of_lists`. Thanks for the list comprehension answer, I didnt use any of these yet, but I will try to understand it.

Comment: @Blaupunkt Please [edit] the question to clarify that, and provide the expected output. Your question is too vague as it stands. It would also help a ton to move the description out from the comments of the code, and remove the pointless comments like `# going through every element of the sub_list`. Check out [ask] if you want more tips.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know if there is a tuple in `possible_moves` that also occurs in every sub_list of `sum_of_lists`.

That just means that there's a tuple in the intersection of all the lists, so...

```
bool(set(possible_moves).intersection(*sum_of_lists))
```

(Of course you don't need the `bool` call if you use the `set(...)...` in a boolean context like in `if set(...)...:`.)

Comment: ...and if the OP actually needs those repeating tuples, they have them in the resulting `set` (as opposed to my `any/all` solution that is strictly boolean). Nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

The functions [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) can be useful for checks like that.

So to check if a tuple is in ***all*** sub-lists, you can do:

```py
position = (3, 4)
print(all(position in sub_list for sub_list in sum_of_lists))
```

If now you want to check if ***any*** of the positions satisfies that, you can do:

```py
print(any(all(position in sub_list for sub_list in sum_of_lists) for position in possible_moves))
```

Comment: You forgot to delete the all in the second case

Comment: @but-why I didn't. This code checks *if there is a tuple in `possible_moves` that also occurs in every sub_list of `sum_of_lists`* [as the OP requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410371/check-if-an-element-of-a-list-matches-at-least-one-element-of-every-list-in-a-ne/66410686?noredirect=1#comment117406098_66410371)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try not to have three nested for loops. Try using some function.

ex.

```
nested = [[1, (5,3), 3], [1, 2, 3, (5,3)]]
move = (5, 3)
```

First check if an element `e` is in the list:

```
e in lst
```

then use this logic as a lambda function:

```
lambda lst: move in lst
```

then map this function through each list in the big list

```
match_all_lst = map(lambda lst: move in lst, nested)
```

then check for each boolean value in the `match_all_lst` is `True`

```
matches_all = all(match_all_lst)
```

You do not have to handle the early break (short-circuit) if you match a value yourself. Functions like `in` or `all` do it by default.

As I also mentioned, I think you are trying to do something the wrong way. The structure is really bad for what you are trying to achieve. You should consider some kind of ordering, maybe a tree or something else. Please explain in more details about what you are after

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didnt use lambda yet, but I will try to understand it. I will edit my post and try to explain a bit more of why I want to do this.

Comment: @Blaupunkt lambda is just a way to define a function in one line. It's purely equivalent to the syntax with def f(x). One asset is that with lambda you don't have to define the name of the function.

Answer (score -1):

I came out with this solution. Hope I understood the problem well.
Code:

```
possible_moves = [(3,4), (3,5), (3,6)]

sum_of_lists = [
    [(5,5), (5,6), (5,7)],
    [(2,3), (2,2), (2,1), (2,0)],
    [(6,4), (5,4), (4,4), (3,4), (2,4)]
]

for x in possible_moves:
    for li_st in sum_of_lists:
        if x in li_st:
            print(f'Found {x} in Given Sum of Lists')
```

Comment: Also note that you print found for a specific sub list. OP wants to know if the element exists in ***all*** sub lists

Comment: Let him do that part. It should not be like only copy and paste the code directly.